# How to validate transactions on private network？

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, genesis, verify, private-ethereum

I'm currently launching a private network using `genesis.json`. We ran two nodes to process transactions from miners. I would like to check whether the other node (verifier) is validating the transaction result. What should I do? My geth is from a version before `--mine` and `--miner` were deprecated.
Below is the `genesis.json` I am using:

```
{
    "config": {
      "chainId": 15,
      "homesteadBlock": 0,
      "eip150Block": 0,
      "eip155Block": 0,
      "eip158Block": 0,
      "byzantiumBlock": 0,
      "constantinopleBlock": 0,
      "petersburgBlock": 0,
      "clique": {
        "period": 0,
        "epoch": 30000
      }
    },
    "difficulty": "1",
    "gasLimit": "8000000",
    "extradata": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000088aaEdAdB70a1ed0Cbbb744214f7CC4Ad8D429b20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "alloc": {
      "bc8b56762B9950886B0056374ff325222d16e040": { "balance": "10000000000000000000" },
      "88aaEdAdB70a1ed0Cbbb744214f7CC4Ad8D429b2": { "balance": "10000000000000000000" }
    }
  }
```

Also, below are the command line arguments passed to geth.

```
./build/bin/geth --datadir ./geth-network/miner/ --syncmode "full" --nodiscover --nat=none --port 30304 --verbosity 5 --networkid 15 --http --http.addr "localhost" --http.api "personal,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner,admin" --http.port 8552 --http.corsdomain "*" --rpc.allow-unprotected-txs --authrpc.port 8553 --allow-insecure-unlock --keystore ./geth-network/miner/keystore/ --unlock 0x88aaEdAdB70a1ed0Cbbb744214f7CC4Ad8D429b2 --password ./geth-network/miner/keystore/pw1.txt --mine --miner.etherbase 0x88aaEdAdB70a1ed0Cbbb744214f7CC4Ad8D429b2
```